# Android support library 27, Fragment update?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-support-library, android-8.0-oreo

Since I updated my project to SDK version 27 and gradle plugins for the support library to version `27.0.0` I needed to change my code.

With `26.1.0` I can just use `getContext()` (with Kotlin `context`) in my `Fragment` (`android.support.v4.app`) and I have no nullability issues, but since I use Kotlin I have a problem with version `27.0.0`, all my `context` calls did not work anymore, I needed a safety operator, like `context!!`, but since I personally find it to be a hustle to do that every time I just made myself I workaround function

```
override fun getContext() = super.getContext()!!
```

Another thing that change (suddenly and that is why I am asking) are the methods `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`. In `onCreateView` the inflater is not possibly null anymore, so I needed to change my function signature to properly override from `onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?...)` to `onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater...)` and the same for the `createdView` parameter in `onViewCreated`.

So now I was wondering why, especially the (for Kotlin) very ugly `getContext()` change was made and headed over to https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/27.0.0/changes.html.

But wait, apparently they did not change it? So now my question is if I am doing something wrong or if they really changed it and if so I might ask them why?

By the way, same applies for `getActivity()`, I think the `mHost == null` check was added and the `getActivity` method is even final, so I cannot use my workaround there, which makes it very very ugly. Actually in the source files the methods look like the same, but `26.1.0` has Kotlin return type `Context!` and `27.0.0` return type `Context?`.

Comment: Sligthly related... non null inflater means fragmen with no ui but used as worker are not an alternative now?

Comment: @cutiko I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These were deliberate changes. Before this version of the support library, these classes had no nullability annotations, so from Kotlin, all these types were just [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). In 27, they added the necessary annotations, so now these types are definitely marked as either nullable or non-nullable in Kotlin - there's no need to guess whether they can be `null`.

As for the specific methods you've mentioned:

- The `getActivity` and `getContext` methods return nullable types because when the `Fragment` is not attached to an `Activity`, these methods already returned `null`. There's no change in behaviour, it's just explicitly marked now, so you can safely handle it.
- The `inflater` parameter of the `onCreateView` method used to be a platform type, so it was up to you whether you marked it nullable or not. Since it will never be called with `null`, it has been explicitly annotated as `@NonNull`, so its type in Kotlin now is strictly `LayoutInflater` instead of the "looser" `LayoutInflater!` type.

---

Edit: starting from support library 27.1.0, you can use the [`requireActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requireActivity()) and [`requireContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requireContext()) methods, which return non-nullable types, with the caveat that they'll throw an `IllegalStateException` when the regular methods would return `null`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is very ugly for Kotlin because `getContext()` in my case will never be null, nor `getActivity()`. That means that I now need to assert `!!` behind them for every call, which is very annoying.

Comment: Note that if the method can be called where activity/fragment is null, you might want to handle it differently than using the null assertion `!!`. Another approach is to use e.g. `activity?.let { /* Do something*/ }`

Comment: starting from 27.1.0 you can use requireContext() and requireActivity()  methods

Comment: @Fhl Instead of using `context!!` or `context?.let{}` you can use `(context ?: return)`.

Comment: Tip: in some cases the Android Studio 'intuition' (Alt + Enter) that offers to wrap in a `context?.let { ... }` or `activity?.let { ... }` call can be handy for quick refactoring.