# Context null , getting NPEs all of a sudden after moving to API 27

Tags: java, android, crash, kotlin, crashlytics

After upgrading to API 27 , I am seeing crashes of context being null in various places not seen before on Crashlytics.
Has something changed ? 
How to fix this ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250787/android-support-library-27-fragment-update)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!!`, for fix this.
But the best solution, will use `?` and `?.let` for null safety.