# Android: Pass instance of MainActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, oncreate

I need the MainActivity-object as context in a Fragment-object.

1. Passing MainActivity as 'this' to a custom constructor of a Fragment-class works only when starting up the app. When rotating it calls the standard, null-argument-constructor via `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
2. Creating a new instance of MainActivity in Fragment does not work either. E.g:

   `MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
   AdapterTasks at = new AdapterTasks(ma,title, subt, imgid);`

-->System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

How can I get a reference from the MainActivity object to a Fragment-object??

Answer (score 3):

If using Java, you can simply call `getActivity()`

If you're using Kotlin, you can also use `requireActivity()` which returns a non-null where `getActivity()` returns nullable, causing you to have lots of null checks in your code.

Comment: Just wonder how it would behave within `onDetach()` ...I'd prefer `null` over whatever else it may return. Trading null-checks for lots of `?`, `!!`, ...is not much better and the question seems to be Java, else there wouldn't be any `;`.

Comment: If you use requireActivity or requireContext it will throw an exception if null.
This SO post has a pretty good explanation of require methods  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289281/android-support-library-27-1-0-new-methods-requireactivity-requirecontext/49289578 
Or you can take a look at some explanation here https://android.jlelse.eu/the-requireactivity-and-requirecontext-example-1c089ce11a3a
I know that the question was asked in Java but I thought a Kotlin answer may be useful to somebody else who may have a similar question. I will edit my answer to support both

Answer (score 2):

Within a `Fragment`, simply call `this.getContext()`.

Or when you need to access something in the *parent* `MainActivity`:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
```

Both only works while the `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity`. Generally, `this.getContext()` prevents one to add too much code into the `Activity`, which rather should be added into the `Fragment`. One can do quite anything in a `Fragment`, while letting the `Activity` inflate it.

Comment: What is actually the difference between 'context' and 'activity'?

Comment: @Jomme https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context ... it's `ContextThemeWrapper` vs. `ContextWrapper`...there's also `getApplicationContext()`, which also has no theme (and it can get tricky, when passing the wrong one `Context` without a theme, when one would require one). It's not documented too well, but it's an important difference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the MainActivity.

On your fragment, use this:

```
activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```