# IllegalStateException in error log for my Fragment using AndroidX library

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, androidx

I used `Fragments` in my small project (i know ... fragments are weird) and I recently implemented `Firebase` to my project. I saw crash on **Android 7.0** device with weird exception without any hint on what was a cause. I checked row from exception, but its simple `EditText` initialization and creating `Toast`. My only guess is that `context` was `null`, but then it should not be executed, because it was wrapped in `?.let` function.

Anyone experienced this exception before?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:696)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:760)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:782)
  at online.myproject.myproject.fragments.entityCreationFragments.ExtEntityFragment$createNewExtEntity$$inlined$let$lambda$1.invoke (ExtEntityFragment.kt:322)
```

Row 322 is this code:

```
context?.let { c -> createToast(getString(R.string.object_creation_success), c)}
```

Comment: Can be useful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250787/android-support-library-27-fragment-update)

Comment: It's the `getString()` call and not `context`. However if `context` in your code is the kotlin syntax sugar for `getContext()` and it's not null, then `requireContext()` should not throw here.

Comment: Yes, context is getContext(). Really weird error